# Automator Service action not showing in keyboard shortcuts list

Tags: keyboard, automator, shortcut

I've followed this tutorial because I want to save audio to my clipboard:
[https://game2text.com/resources/macos/audio-to-clipboard/#:~:text=Hit%20Command%2BS%20and%20name%20it%20as%20Voice%20To%20Clipboard.&text=Then%20go%20to%20System%20Preferences,the%20service%20Voice%20To%20Clipboard](https://game2text.com/resources/macos/audio-to-clipboard/#:%7E:text=Hit%20Command%2BS%20and%20name%20it%20as%20Voice%20To%20Clipboard.&text=Then%20go%20to%20System%20Preferences,the%20service%20Voice%20To%20Clipboard).

The problem is I do not have an "General" folder in System Preferences>Keyboard>Shortcuts in the Services tab. I've tried searching for the problem and the only solution solved solution was that their file was found in the "Files and Folders" folder in service, but it's not there either. If you look the tutorial I have created both Automations and have put them into the Library/Services folder but they're not showing up in Services in the Keyboard Shortcut settings.

Anything I could do?

Comment: Okay apparently all it took was for me to close the Automator app... and it's showing now.

Comment: I had to restart the System Prefs app too. Thanks for posting.